# How to make <div> resizeable?

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, resize

Is there a way to make a `<div>` container resizeable with drag & drop?

Answer (score 86):

The best method would be to use CSS3. It supported by at least Webkit and Gecko.

According to the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize):

```
div.my_class {
    resize:both;
    overflow:auto; /* something other than visible */
}
```

Webkit and Firefox do not interpret the specs the same way. In Webkit the size is limited to the width and height set. There's another question: [How can I use CSS to make an element resizable to a dimension smaller than the initial one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178301/how-can-i-use-css-resize-to-resize-an-element-to-a-height-width-less-than-init) concerning this.

Comment: that only allows you to resize from a corner right?

Comment: @Irfan it is possible like below.

.resizable-content {
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: fit-content;
    max-width: fit-content;
}

Comment: That resize "grabber", in the bottom-right corner, is [way to small in Chromium 69 on a 4K monitor](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884575) and its style isn't accessible via CSS; you can't scale it larger (at the time of this writing).

Comment: Is it possible to grab the div by a specific side?

Answer (score 16):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.resizable-content {
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable-content">Resize Me!</div>
```

Comment: There is already an answer making use of css3 "resize". Aside from this, can you please add some explaining words.

Comment: I just wanted to show how that it is possible to resize lower than the set width and the height for the div .since someone above said that it is not!

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: This only resizes vertically, not horizontally.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with the CSS3-only method is that only the bottom-right-hand corner of the div becomes draggable. Users will almost surely want to resize the div from *any* of the borders, not just the bottom-right-hand corner.

After wasting a bunch of time trying to accomplish this via copying code-snippets from Stack Overflow, I would highly recommend just using the excellent [InteractJS JavaScript library](https://interactjs.io) in your project. It allows to you easily create a resizable (and draggable) div that can be resized from all sides.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let root = document.documentElement;
        let spliter = document.querySelector('.spliter-div');
        let rowDiv = document.querySelector('.row-divs');
        let cd1 = document.getElementById('cd-1');
        var isDown = false;
        var isHover = false;
        var minWidth = 127;
        var maxWidth = 600;

        function setPosition() {
            var cl = this.document.querySelector('.col-div');
            if (cl) {
                root.style.setProperty('--m-x', (cl.offsetWidth + 3.5) + 'px');
            }
            minWidth = (parseInt(rowDiv.clientWidth / 10) * 2) + 22;
            maxWidth = parseInt(rowDiv.clientWidth - minWidth);
        }
        function moveTo(e) {
            if (e.clientX > minWidth && e.clientX < maxWidth) {
                if (cd1.classList.contains('col-div-flex')) {
                    cd1.classList.remove('col-div-flex');
                }
                cd1.style.width = e.clientX  + 'px';
                root.style.setProperty('--m-x', (e.clientX + 9.5) + 'px');
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
            setPosition();
        });
        window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
            setPosition();
        });
        root.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            if (isHover) {
                isDown = true;
            }
        }, true);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            isDown = false;
            if (isHover) {
                //...
            }
        }, true);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            if (isDown) {
                moveTo(e);
            }
        });
        spliter.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
            isHover = true;
            spliter.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
        });
        spliter.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            isHover = false;
        });
```

```css
:root{
    --m-x: 0px;
}

html,
body{
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% ;
    margin: 0 ;
    overflow: hidden ;
}

body{
    margin-bottom: 60px ;
}

.container-divs{
    display: flex ;
    flex: 1 1 auto ;
    height: 100% ;
    width: 100% ;
}

.row-divs{
    display: flex ;
    width: 100% ;
}

.col-div{
    margin: 3px ;
    padding: 3px ;
    min-width: 20% ;
    max-width: 80% ;
}

.col-div-flex{
    flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.border-div{
    border: 1px #a3a3a3 ridge;
    border-radius: 9px;
}

.spliter-div{
    width: 5px ;
    height: 96% ;
    margin: 3px 0;
    background: #9a969676;
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--m-x);
    margin-top: 9px ;
    cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Divs - Resizeable</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-divs">
        <div class="row-divs">
            <div id="cd-1" class="col-div col-div-flex border-div" style="background-color:#d5ff00f7">
            </div>
            <div class="spliter-div"></div>
            <div id="cd-2" class="col-div col-div-flex border-div" style="background-color: #6719b5e2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to execute some function ***doOnResize(tag)*** for every tag (also the <div>) among the array of *mustberesizeable* **tags**, you could simple copy this array to **window**'s one:

```
window[WIN_RESIZED] = [] // init the window's array
for (var i in tags) {      
  window[WIN_RESIZED].push(tags[i])
}
```

and after that set

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
  for (var i in window[WIN_RESIZED]) {
    doOnResize(window[WIN_RESIZED][i])
  }
})
```

where somewehere in the beginning must be written

```
const WIN_RESIZED = 'move_resized_divs'
```

with arbitrary name like '*move_resized_divs*'