# div resizable like text-area

Tags: html, css, textarea

Browsers allow text-areas to be re-sized by dragging their corner by default. I was wondering if this rule could be applied to other elements (a div for instance). I know this effect could be achieved using the jQuery `draggable` or the jQuery-ui `resizable` function, but I would like to do it with plain html / css if it is possible to avoid relying on that library. Are their any CSS rules that I could apply to a div to make it behave in this way?

If you have any other solution I would like to hear it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make <div> resizeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391440/make-div-resizeable)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the css3 [`resize`](http://www.css3.info/preview/resize/) property.

```
div {
    resize: both;
}
```

There is also a `resize: horizontal` and `resize: vertical`.

---

Not currently cross browser http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize

Comment: This is awesome, unfortunatelly it is not working in any IE version. Is there a way to support such a resise to IE?

Comment: you may need to `overflow: auto;` also

Comment: When I do this all sub-elements also get handles. Why is this?

Comment: @ErikAigner You need to make your selector more specific, then.

Comment: how can I move the resize button to the top left of the div?

Comment: You also have to provide some `overflow` property, like `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 41):

You can do this using CSS3. You can create a user resizable `div` tag by setting the resize and overflow styles.
I have set resize to both horizontal and vertical here:

```css
.isResizable {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 90px;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="isResizable">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Any chance you know if it's possible to do without jquery the same but making the grip you click to resize, the whole side of a div? Like on stackoverflow when you post a topic the whole bottom can be taken.