# Enable resize for div inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with contenteditable set to true. Now I want to enable resize for div inside contenteditable div.

In my example html insert works fine but how to make inserted html div to be resizable?

Code:

```
function inserthtml() {
    var sel = document.selection;
    if (sel) {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        document.execCommand('inserthtml', false, "<div><img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'  height='42' width='42'></div>");
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    } else {
        document.execCommand('inserthtml', false, "<div><img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'  height='42' width='42'></div>");
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6q05f1b/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make <div> resizeable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391440/make-div-resizeable)

Comment: Luis, this is not dublicate with post you mentioned. In my case div contenteditable is set to true. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you may use css3 property resize:both; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp or you can also use JQuery UI http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: akshayk, I tried already but no luck. Can you update my fiddle so I can see how it works?

Answer (score 7):

```css
#editme {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="editme" contenteditable="true">Click somewhere in here and press the 'insert html' button</div>
```