# Why is overflow != visible required for any div to be resizabel with resize css property?

Tags: html, css, w3c

I have been reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391773/3429430) about how to make a div resizable. What I don'
t understand is why does the `overflow` property have to be different from `visible`? Both the w3c docs and [csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/resize/) blog mention this.  Is there any specific reason behind this? If yes then what?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the overflow options, setting this value to visible will prevent the box to wrap the content, instead the content will go out of the box. Therefore, if the user is dynamically modifying the box, you would get the context overlapping your element's box.

reference: [mdn overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: But what if I wanted to let the content go out with the resizability feature too? Was this the only reason w3c made it this way?

Comment: That seems to be the case, since that is how the rule was specified; however if you look at the definition there are some exeptions elements that can use resize without overflow being defined: iframes, imgs, video, svg, object, picture and object